# mxgraph custom vertex as image

Tags: javascript, jgraph, mxgraph

Can someone point me where/how to set the vertex to image? I want the shape to be similar to the icon I dragged/dropped in the graph. At the moment when I drag/drop icon on the graph its just showing a rect shape.

toolbar icon

```
<add as="Customers" template="customers" icon=".../getCustomers.png" style="customer;image=images/dude3.png"/> <br/> <br/>

<add as="customers">
        <add as="customers" value="1"/>
        <add as="fillColor" value="#93C47D"/> <!--shape color-->
    </add>
```

I tried adding shape and imagePath but that didn't work.

```
<add as="shape" value="imagePath"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Needs an `image`:

```
<add as="imageCell">
    <add as="shape" value="image"/>
    <add as="perimeter" value="rectanglePerimeter"/>
    <add as="fontSize" value="10"/>
    <add as="align" value="center"/>
    <add as="verticalAlign" value="middle"/>
    <add as="image" value="images/draw/mxlogo.jpg"/>
</add>
```